# I want to save the last clicked button (the state of recycler view) in shared preferences

Tags: android, kotlin

I am creating a news app, I have a recycler view with buttons that have the name of category of news. I want to save the state of recycler view after I destroyed the app. Example if I click in Sport Categories, after I destroy the app and reopen it, the app should have sport category selected. The code its not having a bug but it doesn't save the state. The code it's written in fragment

Some of my  code

```
var isFilterFromCategories = false

class HomeFragment : Fragment(), Callback, HomePageAdapter.Listener,CategoryListener {
  

    private lateinit var binding : FragmentHomeBinding
    private lateinit var adapter: HomePageAdapter
    private lateinit var menuAdapter: MenuAdapter
    private lateinit var currentCategory : String
    private val viewModel by activityViewModels<ArticleViewModel>()
    private var lastPosition : Int = 0
    private var firstTime = true

     private fun showPopUp(view: View) {
        val popup = PopupMenu(context, view, Gravity.RIGHT)
        popup.inflate(R.menu.content_of_dropdown_menu)

        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener { item: MenuItem? ->

            when (item!!.itemId) {
                R.id.dm_raportimi -> {
                    reportArticle()
                }
            }
            true
        })

        popup.show()
    }


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        val window = requireActivity().window
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.statusBarColor = Color.BLACK


        return binding.root

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val snapHelper = PagerSnapHelper()
        snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(binding.recyclerView)
        setDrawerOpeningFunctionality()


        initRecyclerView()
        initMenuRecyclerView()
        viewModel.initializeList()
        val pref = requireActivity()!!.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        lastPosition = pref.getInt("lastpos",0)
        topMenuRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(lastPosition)

        topMenuRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {

                lastPosition =
                    (topMenuRecyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager?)!!.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()

            }
        })


        viewModel.getArrayList().observe(requireActivity()){
            adapter.setArticles(it)

        }

    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        //save position in Shared Preferences
        val pref = requireActivity()!!.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val e = pref.edit()
        e.putInt("lastpos",lastPosition)
        Log.d("lololo",lastPosition.toString())
        e.apply()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (isFilterFromCategories) {
            isFilterFromCategories = false
            setUpComingFromCategorySelection()
        }
    }

    private fun initRecyclerView(){

        adapter = HomePageAdapter(requireContext(), this)

        binding.recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }
    private fun initMenuRecyclerView(){
        menuAdapter = MenuAdapter(requireContext(),this)
        binding.topMenuRecyclerView.apply {

            adapter = menuAdapter
        }

    }

    private fun openWebLink(url: String){
        val webIntent: Intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
        startActivity(webIntent)
    }
     private fun shareLink(title: String, url: String){
         val sharingIntent = Intent.createChooser(Intent().apply {

             action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
             putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/")
             putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,url)

             // (Optional) Here we're setting the title of the content
             putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, title)

             // (Optional) Here we're passing a content URI to an image to be displayed
             type = "rext/plain"
             flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
         }, null)
         startActivity(sharingIntent)

     }

    override fun sourceOfInformationClicked(link: String) {
        openWebLink(link)
    }
    override fun shareLinkInformationClicked(name:String, link:String){
        shareLink(name,link)
    }
    override fun showMoreOnClicked(view: View){
        showPopUp(view)
    }

    private fun reportArticle() {
        val action = HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToReportFragment()
        findNavController().navigate(action)
    }
    private fun setDrawerOpeningFunctionality() {
        val drawerLayout = requireActivity().findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawer_layout)
        drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        binding.btnNavDraw.setOnClickListener {
            with(drawerLayout){
                if (!isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)){
                    openDrawer(GravityCompat.END)
                } else {
                    closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun changeCategory(category: String){
        viewModel.setNews(category)
        binding.topMenuRecyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()

    }

    override fun selectCategoryListener(category: String, pos: Int) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
    private fun setUpComingFromCategorySelection(){
        val args: HomeFragmentArgs by navArgs()
            currentCategory = args.category
            menuAdapter.setCategory(currentCategory)
        menuAdapter.selected.add(args.position)
        binding.topMenuRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(args.position)
        viewModel.setNews(currentCategory)
        }
}
```

Comment: If the code doesn't do what you want it to, it does have a bug. :-)

Comment: Can you edit your question to also show the code where you populate the data in the recycler view adapter? I think your main problem is probably calling `scrollToPosition()` before there is anything to scroll to. Also, `onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to be called so you should use `onStop()` instead.

Comment: True, it does have a bug.  I meant it does not show an error :) . I edited the code, now it's the whole fragment . I am using two recycler views, one for the news that we filter when we select a category and one for the categories.

Comment: Oh, I see you're using data binding. I'm not sure if data binding has some way to respond each time data is updated. You need to scroll to position after the first time data arrives for the adapter. If you weren't using data binding, you could do this in the LiveData observer or Flow collector.

Comment: You were right, I used onStop() instead of onDestroy() but it only saves the position, nothing else. My news doesn't filter, and the button does not take the view that it's selected.

Comment: Yes, I think you need to add a data binding property observer that calls `scrollToPosition()` the first time the data arrives for the recycler view.  Without that, you are calling it before there is any data, so it doesn't scroll. I don't know exactly how to do this because I don't use data binding.

Comment: Well, thank you a lot for your answers, you were helpful in a way :)

Answer (score 0):

You should save position on item click.Dont save position on onDestroy

```
private const val TAG = "DeviceAdapter"
class DeviceAdapter(
private val context: Context
, private val list: MutableList<UsbDevice>
, private val callback: (device: UsbDevice) -> Unit): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    val binding = ItemDeviceBinding.inflate(inflater,parent,false)
    return MyViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val device = list[position]
    if (holder is MyViewHolder){
        holder.binding.textHere.text = device.deviceName

        holder.binding.textHere.setOnClickListener {
            val pref = context.getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREFERENCES_KEY",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            val editor = pref.edit()
            editor.putInt("lastPos",position)
            editor.apply()
     
        }
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return list.size
}

class MyViewHolder(val binding: ItemDeviceBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
```

}

Comment: I don't think it would be good user experience to ask the user to press a button before leaving your app every time.

Comment: He wants to save position of item which he clicked...so for this it is okay

Comment: I don't think they said that. They said they wanted to save the current scroll position.

Comment: Example if I click in Sport Categories, after I destroy the app and reopen it, the app should have sport category selected.......he said that ... if i misunderstood ,,sorry for that

Comment: Oh, you're right, they did say that. Their code makes no attempt at doing it in the click listener, so I assumed they just wanted the last position seen when the app closed. Anyway, I think their actual problem in the question is that it is not restoring the saved position.